# Broadcom 4312 wireless not working on an HP dv6-1245 DX

Tags: wireless, drivers, 10.04, broadcom, hp-pavilion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my HP dv6-1245 dx notebook and I do not have any wifi (it worked perfectly in windows vista and 7). I have followed a lot of instructions found on net but still not able to get Internet. 
Here is the outcome of `lspci`:

```
$ sudo lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) 
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) 
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03) 
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03) 
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) 
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03) 
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03) 
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03) 
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03) 
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) 
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) 
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) 
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03) 
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) 
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03) 
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03) 
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem (rev 03) 
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01) 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

I have used ndiswrapper and have installed it, as well as the windows drivers for Broadcom, no change.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

If "An unsupported BCM4312 Low-Power (LP-PHY) device was found." also install

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Then reboot

Instructions on how to install firmware for Broadcom chips.

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

Comment: The first line only is what I have to do on my dv5000 series, except I don't mess with the `firmware-b43legacy-installer`. You might have to use it though. I don't even have to reboot, I just make sure the manual switch is turned on for the wireless.  If you don't want to do it through console you can use Synaptic Package Manager and search for it there.  I still have to use it on 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try this driver.
`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
and if that fails, remove it and try
`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`